# Directory listing outside index.html

Tags: apache

I have a static website on an Apache server. I have an folder (who's name I don't give out to anyone else) that I don't want anyone to randomly stumble upon. Is there any way to have directory listing under a different page?

To clarify, I have directory listing turned off at the root folder of `example.com`. In the subfolder that correspondes to `example.com/folder1/`, I have another .htaccess that allows directory listing. However, I don't want someone who types in `example.com/folder1/index.html` or the equivalent to see the directory listing. I want them to have to go to `example.com/folder1/otherindex.html` to see the listing.

Is this possible with Apache?

Comment: Do you refer to [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_autoindex.html) or to [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)?

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
DirectoryIndex  filename
```

in your .htaccess

Comment: Do I have to create that file? If so, what do I put in it? If not, this does not seem to work. It just bypasses the blank `index.html` I have setup and displays a directory list, which is exactly what I do *not* want.

Comment: Sorry got your idea now .... hmmm I can only think of a kind of a hack: any folder you want an automatic file list generated is in general open to the user unless it is outside the root and you point to it with an alias. If you set the alias for your desired .html it might work (I am not 100% sure if you can set an alias for a file): alias /folder/xyz.html d:/..../  but I did not try it!!